# Como encaixar perguntas sobre modelagem?

Tags: debate, fechamento, escopo-do-site

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307469/poo-em-java-modelagem-copa-do-mundo) foi fechada.

Estou estudando UML e gostaria de fazer perguntas nessa linha mas vejo que poderão não ser bem recebidas.

Existe um jeito de encaixar esse tipo de pergunta, avaliando a modelagem das classes ou a descrição de casos de uso, ou não tem jeito mesmo?

Comment: Estou curioso, se perguntas relacionadas a isso são consideradas fora de escopo, por que existe a tag uml?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Talvez para dúvidas referentes à sintaxe da UML, mas concordo que o escopo poderia ser mais amplo.

Comment: Acredito que o que levou ao fechamento não foi o assunto mas a forma como foi perguntada, entretanto discordo do motivo de fechamento, poderia ser ampla de mais ao meu ver já que o AP pede orientações e não uma dúvida específica.

Comment: @Math Entendi. Mas a dúvida permanece, perguntas do tipo "avaliem o meu design" não são bem-vindas?

Comment: Acredito que se encaixe como for de escopo por ser baseado em opiniões ou ampla demais, mas eu acho q o mais indicado é você fazer uma pergunta de verdade no site e ver no que dá, se fecharem você traz para o meta. Você pode tentar ser mais específico sempre que possível, tentando focar em uma dúvida sua do que simplesmente um pedir UML review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que a pergunta seria melhor recebida se ela fosse mais específica. O usuário não explicou sua dúvida, dificuldade ou apresentou algum código (mesmo colocando a tag `java` nela). Foi colocado apenas uma imagem e exposta uma dificuldade na modelagem sem dizer qual era. A imagem, por si só, já é bem prejudicial ao site se não for algo complementar para entendimento de um texto ou código.

O motivo dado como fechamento da pergunta pode ter sido equivocado, pois não acho que a pergunta esteja fora do escopo mas sim muito ampla.

Answer (score 5):

O segredo é **expor uma parte pequena e solucionável do seu problema de uma forma suscinta, bem redigida e esclarecedora**.

Estes sao os requisitos de qualquer pergunta mesmo, mas se quer fazer uma pergunta sobre modelagem entao estes requisitos sao ainda mais importantes, uma vez que voce nao tem uma implementacao concreta ainda (nao ha nenhum código para analizar).

Creio que este seja um dos motivos que essas perguntas tendam a ser fechadas, uma vez que esses requisitos nao sao fáceis de cumprir e quem pergunta dificilmente os cumpre.

De forma, a que se voce quiser a sua pergunta a ser respondida e nao fechada voce tem que **ser especifico**. Quanto mais especifico voce for melhor, porque o conjunto possiveis de solucoes serao também serao menores.

Por outro lado, se voce nao for especifico, as respostas nao vao ser úteis, uma vez que há menos restricoes, há também um conjunto maior de opcoes e dessa forma as respostas serao mais opinitativas.

Fica aqui um exemplo duma pergunta de modelagem que eu respondi e foi relativamente bem recebido. [Como realizar o desvio de fluxo correto em uma integração com vários sistemas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220362)